# How can I solve the problem of "missing GUROBI_LIBRARY"?

Tags: cmake, build, ros, gurobi

I encountered the following problem when I was trying to run the code from [Fast and Safe Trajectory Planner for Flights in Unknown Environments](https://github.com/mit-acl/faster)

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find GUROBI (missing: GUROBI_LIBRARY)
```

I think I followed all the instructions correctly and the file `~/.bashrc` is appended with the following statements:

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
export GUROBI_HOME="/home/zjnyly/Desktop/gurobi911/linux64"
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
export GRB_LICENSE_FILE="/home/zjnyly/gurobi.lic"
source /home/zjnyly/Desktop/ws//devel/setup.bash
```

I then tried to change the version of gurobi manully in FindGUROBI.cmake file, but I don't know how to correctly write it.
(the version of gurobi on my computer is 9.1.1)

```
find_library(GUROBI_LIBRARY
NAMES gurobi gurobi91
HINTS ${GUROBI_DIR} $ENV{GUROBI_HOME}
PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
```

I'm new to this field and I don't know much about these things. I'd appreciate it if you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: `is appended with the following statements:` Did you open a new shell?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not set your environment variables correctly, please check.
As the work only tested in Ubuntu 16.04/ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 18.04/ROS Melodic and
Gurobi 8.1, Gurobi 9.0, and Gurobi 9.1. so use the relevant version.